# Visual Basic for Excel: Remove column headers

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet as table with the first row as the column headers. I'm trying to remove them being column headers without having to delete the entire row using Visual Basic.

Is there a Visual Basic script or cell property that removes it being a column header?

Comment: Try recording a macro of you doing it manually first. That will give you code to start with.

Comment: Do you mean VBA or Visual Basic? If in Excel and VBA and your data is a table what are you planning on doing about a requirement for headers?

Comment: Sorry, not VBA at all. Fixed tag. It's just for printing purposes, not for data management/storage.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to braX for the Macro recording suggestion. The macro is of the form:

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ShowHeaders = False